# Problem understanding the filter function

Tags: filter, sapui5

Here given is the functionality to add a filter and searchbar feature on a page

I am having trouble understanding the given `onFilterInvoices` function used to filter the list shown on the screen.

```
#InvoiceList.controller.js
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
    "../model/formatter",
    "sap/ui/model/Filter",
    "sap/ui/model/FilterOperator"
], function (Controller, JSONModel, formatter , Filter, FilterOperator) {
    "use strict";
    return Controller.extend("Workspace.controller.InvoiceList", {
        formatter: formatter,
        onInit : function () {
            var oViewModel = new JSONModel({
                currency: "EUR"
            });
            this.getView().setModel(oViewModel, "view");
        },
        onFilterInvoices : function (oEvent) {

            var aFilter = [];
            var sQuery = oEvent.getParameter("query");
            if (sQuery) {
                aFilter.push(new Filter("ProductName", FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery));
            }           
            var oList = this.byId("invoiceList");
            var oBinding = oList.getBinding("items");
            oBinding.filter(aFilter);
        }
    });
});
```

You can refer the [Filtering](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/5295470d7eee46c1898ee46c1b9ad763) code

Comment: Hi Aayushk, could you explain which is the problem? The function seems to be easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to explain. First, read : [sap.ui.model.Filter](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.Filter/methods/Summary)

Let's look at:

`new Filter("ProductName", FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery)`

A filter needs 3 things:

1. Where to look for data.
2. How to look into data.
3. What to look into data.

Let's apply this:

So we are creating a filter,

1. Which will look for property `ProductName` (which stores the name of product) in our model which is bound to our list.
2. Now, it needs to know how to look. Basically the operations. These operations can be `contains`, `equals`, `greater than`, `less than` etc. So we are saying,

   `if ( ProductName.indexOf() > -1 ) {
     return ProductName;
   }`
3. What to look for in data ( which is whatever user enters in the search input box). As you can, in above code, the `indexOf` needs a parameter. `sQuery` is that parameter. So, lets complete our code:

   `if ( ProductName.indexOf(sQuery) > -1 ) {
    return ProductName;
   }`

The above statement in executed once for all the elements in the model (more below) and hence, whenever the above condition is met, that element in returned and element get bound to the list.

Two points to consider here:

1. My List is bound to a specific path. Does it really need to loop through all the data in model ? No. It needs the path in model where the list is bound. Hence, we need the List Binding which will tell the path. Try this and look how much info its stores about the binding:

`console.log(oList.getBinding("items"));`

2. If my model is bound to multiple list, should filtering in 1 list impact other places?
   No, only where I searched. Hence, we dont need to apply filter on the model but on the List Binding specific to a list. Just update the list which I'm trying to filter. Hence, we fetch the binding of the list using:

`oList.getBinding('items')`.

Now, the code: `oBinding.filter(aFilter);`.

Its a call to UI5 API: Hey, I want to apply filter to this specific list binding(show only matching items). Here is the filters(array) as parameter. UI5 then executes the filter, updates the UI.

Hope this helps.